# shared Workstation with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, xserver

This is kind of an awkward question but here I go. Is it possible to have a shared Workstation for two users? each user would have its own pair of screens, mouse, keyboard etc but each working in its own home directory etc? Is there any server packages combination that would allow this? Otherwise what is the easiest combination of packages to allow WLAN network login and running not only shells on the shared box but also development IDE like e.g. Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you are asking.

The first step is to give each user a unique account. This way each user will have a personal home directory.

In addition, I think what you are asking about would be "multiseat".

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

http://www.linuxtoys.org/multiubuntu/multiubuntu.html